# SQL Server Compact Edition Set Up

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, ssms, backend

I have downloaded both SQL Server Express and Compact edition

I can only see the Express edition in the SSMS

How to **find** the SQL Server Compact Edition?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server **Compact Edition** is a file-based solution (using `.sdf` files), not a server-based solution like SQL Server Express - and therefore SQL Server CE **cannot** be managed/handled by SQL Server Mgmt Studio. You'll need something like [the SQL Server CE Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) to look at those `.sdf` files and their contents

Comment: Thanks Marc, appreciate it

Comment: Only SSMS Express has such a constraint (and I really don't know why). If you use any other version, you can manage SQL Server CE .sdf files.

Comment: I'm running Compact Edition, so that explains the problem, thanks Ozren

Comment: @marc_s, I think you should make it an answer (I mean the same comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server **Compact Edition** is a file-based solution (using `.sdf` files), not a server-based solution like SQL Server Express.

Therefore SQL Server CE cannot (really) be managed/handled by SQL Server Management Studio. (*I do know - some people claim you can - but I personally have never been able to open any `.sdf` file in any version of SQL Server Management Server*).

You'll need something like the **SQL Server CE Toolbox** to look at those `.sdf` files and their contents